# async shell command バッファに exit code をひも付けて取得ないし表示したい

Tags: emacs, elisp

`M-&` などで `shell-command` を実行すると、`*Async Shell Command*`　バッファが作成されますが、対応するプロセスが終了した時点で、このバッファに exit code をひも付け、それを取得ないし表示ことはできますでしょうか。

特に、複数個のプロセスを同時に、非同期で実行する場合などにおいて、 `*Async Shell Command*` を`rename-uniquely` などで rename して、複数個作成することがよくあります。
その際に、どのバッファ(を出力しているプロセス)がどの exit code であったかを、そのバッファから取得する方法が欲しくなるので、質問しました。

Comment: shell-commandであれば関数として呼び出し, その戻り値を使うという方法がありますが, M-&, async-shell-commandについては取得することはできません. `M-& somecommand ; echo $?` のように実行して exit statusも一緒に表示させるようなコマンドを与えるぐらいでしょうか.

Comment: @syohex 確かに、その方法で、目的の「終了した際に exit code を表示する」 は実現できますね。その方法は思い至りませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「M-& など」という事ですが、ここでは `async-shell-command` に限って話を進めたいと思います。

`async-shell-command` の実行の流れとしては以下の通りです。

- async-shell-command
- shell-command
- start-process
- (set-process-sentinel proc 'shell-command-sentinel)

最終的に `set-process-sentinel` で実行プロセスの管理が開始されます(process status が変化する度に `shell-command-sentinel` が実行されます)。

そこで、この `shell-command-sentinel` にフックを付けます。具体的には `nadvice` を使います。

```
(defun set-async-process-exit-status (process signal)
  (when (eq (process-status process) 'exit)
    (let ((buf (process-buffer process))
          (st (process-exit-status process)))
      (when (string-match "Async Shell Command" (buffer-name buf))
        (set-buffer buf)
        (setq-local exit-status st)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (insert (format "\nExit status: %d\n" st))))))

(advice-add 'shell-command-sentinel :before #'set-async-process-exit-status)
```

詳しい説明は省きますが、プロセスが終了した段階で `*Async Shell Command*` バッファに buffer local な変数である `exit-status` にプロセスの exit status をセットして、その値をバッファの最後に表示します。

```
M-& 
Async shell command: ls
     :

(assoc 'exit-status (buffer-local-variables (get-buffer "*Async Shell Command*")))
=> (exit-status . 0)

M-& 
Async shell command: hogehoge
     :

(assoc 'exit-status (buffer-local-variables (get-buffer "*Async Shell Command*")))
=> (exit-status . 127)
```

`(string-match "Async Shell Command" (buffer-name buf))` としている部分が `async-shell-command` に依存していますので、`async-shell-command` 以外の elisp 関数で同じことを行う場合には適宜変更する必要があります。